How to debug internet issue on macOS 14.x
I'm using MacBook Air, with M1 chipset running macOS 14.4.1 and connected to my home Wifi. Over the last few days I am facing a weird issue which leads to the internet not working for few apps like Chrome and Slack, whereas on Safari everything works fine at the same time.
Even curl fails with message "Couldn't connect to server" but sudo curl works fine!
Doing a logout-login doesn't solve the issue, restart fixes the issue though.
I've another MacBook Pro running macOS 13, connected to same wifi but haven't observed any such issue on it.
Switching wifi / hotspot doesn't work as well.
Can someone help me how to diagnose this issue? Any log file or tool that we can use to monitor what happened just before the internet stopped working to find the root cause?
